# XmlReader ReadString() removes '\r' from "\r\n"

Tags: c#, winforms, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization, ixmlserializable

I have a class inheriting from `IXmlSerializable`. I've properly overridden the `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` methods.

I am using `XmlSerializer` to Serialize/Deserialize the object to an xml file.

When I `Serialize` the object, it is correctly writing the `\r\n` to the file. But when I `Deserialize` the object the same way, the `\r` has been removed and only the `\n` is present. I can't figure out why it is doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called normalization and explicitly defined in the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#sec-line-ends)

> ... an XML processor must normalize line breaks in parsed entities to #xA either by translating the two-character sequence #xD #xA and any #xD that is not followed by #xA to #xA on input before parsing, ...

Some of the normalizations can be disabled via [XmlTextReader.Normalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.normalization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not using `XmlTextReader`, so that's not an option. When I call `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` and pass the object, the object's inherited method `IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)` is called. I tried to edit the reader's settings on the first line but the settings property is null and has no setter. I wanted to find a solution I could put into my `Serializer` and/or `Deserialzer` methods which handles all objects serialization. But I'm guessing my best option is to add `.Replace("\n", "\r\n")` where needed, unless that's a bad idea?

Comment: What are you using, if not `XmlTextReader`?

Comment: @Paul-SGSPfINDE If re-normalizing `"\n"` to `"\r\n"` works for you it may be reasonable option. Passing properly configured `XmlTextReader` as source is another approach... XML is surprisingly bad format to store arbitrary strings... if you *must* keep strings exactly as they are provided it may be better to treat them as binary data and Base64 encode. XML have very strict rules for characters in 0-32 range as well as surrogate pairs, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to process only `'\n'` for new line in text files. DOS/Windows C libraries have "text mode" which transparently convert CR-LF to LF and back.

Comment: So why does it write `\r\n` to the file? If I just read the text from the file I get the `\r\n` but if I call `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` if reads only `\n`.

Comment: In Unix world, new line in text files is `\n` only. In Windows it is `\r\n` (CR-LF). In Mac it is CR only `\r`. But for compatibility, when you read from text file in C/C++ under Windows, all `\r\n`-s are converted to `\n`. By this way original Unix (console) programs can be compiled under DOS/Windows and they have to work. It is because C language "come" from Unix world.

Comment: Note that this question is about XML: XML have very strict rules on new line handling. While for general text operations \r\n is somewhat follow what you said they are flexible in more or less randomly produce/consue either of the sequences. Compliant XML parser on other hand limited to just exposing `\n` all the time by the specification irrespective of what is in source text. So as long as XML parser is compliant switching between *nix and Windows will not have any effect on *this* issue.

Comment: You are right but in fact XML will have the same "value" even without any new lines. All tags can be at single "line".